# Increasing spark workers and cassandra nodes takes more time

Tags: performance, apache-spark, cassandra, data-partitioning, spark-ui

So, I have a small cluster with 3 Spark workers(2 executors each) and on the same nodes I have also installed Cassandra in order to achieve data locality. In order to evaluate the speed and times(from SparkUI) I run the same code with, firstly one spark-cassandra node, then two and then three spark-cassandra nodes for 3 times in every case. The results are below, but I do not understand why does it take more time with 3 nodes than 2?

[image]

I am not sure what to check. For the above times spark.sql.shuffle.partitions was 96, but I tried also the  "3 / 3" with 18 partitions and it was still the same (3min 13s, 3min 5s, 3min 19s)

What could be happening and why? Please, let me know if you need more information.

**Edit1**

The only difference between the first 2 cases and the 3rd is the replication factor in Cassandra db. For the first 2 is 1 and for the 3rd case is 3. Could that be the reason?network traffic and latencies?

**Edit2**

Below are some pictures from the Stages Tab of SparkUI with 3 spark-cassandra nodes (3rd case).
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what your job is doing on the data ? is it loading all data from Cassandra ? or specific partitions  ?

Comment: The job basically is that it pulls data from cassandra and implements a PCA with SparkML. It loads specific partitions and performs a DirectJoin in between. I updated the question with pictures from SparkUI Stages tab.